# How to list all pages in a path?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a structure like this:

```
pages:
  - route1
     - lots of js page
  - index.js
```

I would like to display a list of all pages under `route1` on my index page.

How can I fetch all available pages?

I tried to use `getStaticProps` in `index` to load all the files using `fs` and `path` but I am not able to `require` all the pages.

```js
export async function fetchPages() {
    const fs = require('fs')
    const path = require('path')

    const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(process.cwd(), '/pages/route1/'))


    return map(files, (f) => {
        return require(path.join(process.cwd(), '/pages/route1/', f))
    })
}
```

but this is not working.

**Edit:** `require` is used to load all the `export` from those pages such as `title` of the page or `excerpt` to display on the `index` page.

**Edit:** The error is `Error: Cannot find module '/path/to/pages/route1/pageName.js'`. Coming from the `require`.

**Edit:** I tried to use [How to generate a menu based on the files in the pages directory in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63692392/how-to-generate-a-menu-based-on-the-files-in-the-pages-directory-in-next-js) but it does not work since in the next config file we have to use `require`/`module.export` but the `require('path/to/page')` is going to bring `react` pages with `import`s and `export`s

Comment: What should `require` do here?

Comment: @Konrad , I edited my post with more info

Comment: Add specific error please

Comment: You might use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63692392/how-to-generate-a-menu-based-on-the-files-in-the-pages-directory-in-next-js as inspiration. I guess your trying to build some dynamic navigation, if so - that question will answer your needs perfectly

Comment: @KlimenkoKirill, I added an edit after trying to use it

Comment: I tried to do it myself and webpack just doesn't let me import things using variables

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a page variable as an Array and push routes ?

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const pages = []

const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(process.cwd(), '/pages/route1/'))

files.forEach((file) => {
  pages.push(require(path.join(process.cwd(), '/pages/route1/', file)))
})

return pages
```

Comment: The error is coming from the `require` not working. It can't find the module

Comment: I didn't have the "edit" when I posted